# Does methyl or aldehyde group have higher priority when choosing the main chain of carbonyl compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, carbonyl-compounds

As far as I know, both following names seem to be correct for the compound below. Please explain which IUPAC name is correct by which IUPAC rules:

[image: 4-formylpentanoic acid vs. 4-methyl-5-oxopentanoic acid]

- **4-formylpentanoic acid** (methyl group counted in the main chain);
- **4-methyl-5-oxopentanoic acid** (aldehyde group counted in the main chain).

Answer (score 5):

Both names 4-formylpentanoic acid and 4-methyl-5-oxopentanoic acid are correct. In particular, the following rules of Section P-44 apply to both names:

- The parent structure has the maximum number of substituents corresponding to the principal characteristic group, which is expressed as a suffix (-oic acid), in accordance with Rule P-44.1.1.
- The principal chain has the greater number of skeletal atoms in accordance with Rule P-44.3.2.
- The principal chain has the lower locant for an attached group expressed as a suffix in accordance with Rule P-44.4.1 (h).

Therefore, we have to consider the Rules of Section P-45 in order to figure out which principal chain will lead to the preferred IUPAC name.

> **P-45 SELECTION OF PREFERRED IUPAC NAMES**
>
> **P-45.0** INTRODUCTION
>
> Two or more names may result based on the same senior parent structure selected
> according to P-44, because of different substitution patterns or multiple ccurrences of the same senior parent structure. A parent structure is defined (P -15.1) as a parent hydride, for example, benzene, a functionalized parent hydride, for example
> cyclohexanol, or a functional parent compound, for example, acetic acid. Application of the criteria in this section will generate the preferred IUPAC name.

The first relevant rule of Section P-45 is about the number of substituents cited as prefixes:

> **P-45.2.1** The preferred IUPAC name is based on the senior parent structure that has the maximum number of substituents cited as prefixes (other than ‘hydro/dehydro’) to the parent structure.

Therefore, the preferred IUPAC name is **4-methyl-5-oxopentanoic acid** (two substituents) rather than 4-formylpentanoic acid (one substituent).

[image: 4-methyl-5-oxopentanoic acid]

The situation would be reversed if we place more substituents on the other chain, e.g. **5,5-dichloro-4-formylpentanoic acid** (three substituents) rather than 4-(dichloromethyl)-5-oxopentanoic acid (two substituents).

[image: 5,5-dichloro-4-formylpentanoic acid]